# Parse different types of data from input java

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

Different lists of data will be entered on command line.

```
"J,A,V,A"
"4,H,11,V,3,H"
```

I need to store the first list in a char array. I also want to have the next line in a char array of "H,V,H" and an int array of "4,11,3".  What is the best way to go about doing this? I'm hesitant to split on the comma because I don't know if the input is going to be separated by just a comma or a comma and a space. I'm having difficulty since when I use a scanner everything stays in a string, and when I try to split it the string becomes a string array.

I'm having difficulty since when I use a scanner everything stays in a string, and when I try to split it the string becomes a string array.

Comment: *"What is the best way to go about doing this?"*  I'd do some research, then try some things.  [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us.

Comment: `str.split("\\s*,\\s*")` will take care of the splitting issue.

Comment: Why did you destroy the edits I made?  Don't edit a post by using the 'back' button.  Instead use the 'edit' link below the post.

Comment: can you explain what this does? ("\\s*,\\s*)

Comment: @arshajii  I think the OP is replying to you.  OP - make sure to notify people using `@PersonName`..

Comment: @user1378762 [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) takes a regular expression. In regex-land, `\s*` means *"zero or more spaces"*. We put this on either side of the comma (escaping the \ with another \ since it's a Java string literal we're dealing with).

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work for me.. Only ran it in the debugger, but it workd on the two lines of input you provided.

```
import java.lang.System;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (console.hasNext()) {
        String line = console.next();
        String[] tokens = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");

        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        if (isInteger(tokens[i])) {
            ints.add(Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]));
        } else if (isChar(tokens[i])) {
            chars.add((char) tokens[i].indexOf(0));
        }
        }

    }
    console.close();

    }

    private static boolean isInteger(String s) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(s);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
        // only got here if we didn't return false
        return true;
    }

private static boolean isChar(String s) {
if (s.length() != 1) {
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

}